# How to insert multiple checkboxes into a database?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I dont know to to insert multiple checkboxes to database it only take the first value of first check box.

```
String SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS = request.getParameter("SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS");
```

that is the code I done so far.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Database">Database<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Web_Programming">WEB PROGRAMMING<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Data_Mining">Data Mining<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Human_Computer Interaction">Human Computer Interaction<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Software_Engineering">Software Engineering<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Information_Retrieval">Information Retrieval<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Software_Quality">Software Quality<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="e-commerce"> e-commerce<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Management_Information Systems,">Management Information Systems<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS" value="Information_Systems">Information Systems<br>
```

Comment: Since you only posted html related code I assume your problem is not how to store multiple values in a database but how to get them from your page to your backend, right? If you do have problems with writing them to the database as well then we need some more information, e.g. what your table looks like and how you try to do the db-related opertions.

Comment: You also should try to read the JavaDoc on method you don't know or that don't do what you want them to do. From the JavaDoc on `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()`: "You should only use this method when you are sure the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more than one value, use `getParameterValues`. "

Comment: A checkbox is a visual element. You don't put that in a database.

Comment: Bad English is not a problem, but we all know, using "I" in lowercase is not because of your English. Here is a downvote to motivate you to use the "I" correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Suppose Your code is in page1.jsp and i am submitting to that in page2.jsp or servlet.to get all the checkbox value you need to write code following way.
String values[] = request.getParameterValues("SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        out.print(values[i]);
    }
```

Comment: i will try it thank a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this String[ ] SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS = request.getParameterValues("SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS");

Comment: '[Ljava.lang.String;9a'   it gives me this .

Comment: You need to convert string array to string use loop

Comment: how i can do that in newbie  sorry please can you make an example ?

Comment: @Override
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException{
  String value=null;
  String[] v=req.getParameterValues("SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS");
  value=v[0];
  for(int i=1;i<v.length;i++)
   value=value+","+v[i];
  res.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
  out.println(value);
 } You can store value variable value into database now